# Is there a better way to let users know to post questions as questions and answers as answers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066411/good-eclipse-rcp-tutorial

It seems to me that there has to be a way to more easily allow people to share things like this. Sure, Digg and Reddit exist for this kind of thing, too, but there has to be some way to leverage Stack Overflow as a link-sharing community, especially since (IMO) it totally beats the other social bookmarking sites when it comes to comments.

Answer (score 3):

StackOverflow is a Q&A site. And it's designed around that.

I think it's working fine as is, you are going to have edge cases like this, but it's not something you need to change the design over.

Comment: I realize that, but there has to be a way to encourage users to post questions as questions, and if they have something to share, to share it as an answer.

Comment: Because I don't mean to add a social bookmarking feature. But just something to encourage people to use the Q/A format.

Comment: True, true. But perhaps it might be something to keep in mind when enhancing or developing new features, as I've seen this happen multiple times, usually resulting in a closure or deletion.

Comment: Of course            .

Answer (score 2):

The best way to let them know is to close the question down as "Not a real question" and let them learn from their mistake. Sometimes the best way to learn to not touch a hot stove is to get burned.

Answer (score 0):

Lead by example.

Just edit their question to match a 'jeopardy' format.

See my edits as an example:

> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1066411/list

Comment: What is this answer makes me laugh?

Comment: I'm Ron Burgundy           ?

Comment: You have changed the entire sense of the question, which I don't think is the point of editing.

Comment: @Tom: Of course it changed. I made a useless question that would likely get downvoted and closed into a question that is actually worth something. And that /is/ the point of editing.

Comment: @Tom: In fact, the OP thanked me for the edit. Care to explain where your problem lies with it?

Comment: seems like an OK edit to me in this case

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: So why did you close it then?